# Trying to cut an image off

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm creating a website in Twitter Bootstrap 3. This is what I have so far.
http://ts-mc.net/

Everything works fine, however, the image on the homepage stretches out. I want to keep it so that the image isn't responsive, that way it works fine on mobile devices, however I'd like to get rid of the excess image that isn't displayed.

Comment: Try to avoid linking to external sites: the question will lose context over time due to link rot and changes. Try porting your question over to a JSfiddle, for example.

Comment: My apologies! I haven't used stackoverflow before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `overflow:hidden` on a container div. See **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L2G2U/)**.

HTML

```
<div><img src='src'></div>
```

CSS

```
div
{
    overflow:hidden;
    width:80px;
}
```

You can set the container div width and height to 100% and then the rest of the image will be cropped.

If it is a background image then use a pseudo element as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777159/clip-crop-background-image-with-css).

**Update**

As you mention `overflow-x:hidden` is a good refinement of `overflow-hidden` if you just want to crop the width.

Comment: Thanks! The overflow: hidden didn't work out for what I needed, however overflow-x: hidden worked just fine!

Comment: @user247301 - glad that you got it. I have updated my answer. You may want to accept it (click the tick) so that it doesn't show up as unanswered.

Comment: Thanks once again, I've ticked it.