# Background image viewport by many-images-in-one-image-file

Tags: html, css, performance, image-clipping

To reduce the loadtime of my webpage I put all icons into one big imagefile.

[image]

What I need now is the fourth icon (attachment-icon) as button icon.

This is what I have:

```css
button.attach {
  background: lightgray url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT5KK.png);
  background-position-x: -116px;
  padding-left:30px;
  height:45px;
  
}
```

```html
<button class="attach"> Attach file</button>
```

Unfortunately the fifth icon (trash) and the sixth icon (bug) sneak behind the text. How to cut the image down to this icon only?

Comment: Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7777159/clip-crop-background-image-with-css).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button.attach span {
    background: lightgray url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZT5KK.png) -111px 38px;
    padding-left: 1px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
}
    button.attach {
    width: 130px;
    height: 44px;
}
```

```html
    <button class="attach"><span></span> Attach file</button>
```

Here i attached css in snippet, you can adjust as per your requirements. let me know if you have any query.